# Tensor product of two injective R-modules is not necessarily injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, injective-module

Would you please help me to find an example of two injective R-modules (R is a commutative ring) for which the tensor product is not injective?

Comment: See this MSE question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623907/is-it-true-that-tensor-product-of-injective-modules-is-injective

Comment: Yes ,thanks,but i could't find any example there...

Comment: And also i'm not familiar with envelope of a ring...